# Mac Excel will not print comments

Tags: excel

I am attempting to print a section of an Excel doc with comments shown. I have went through every tutorial on the internet about how to enable this, and regardless of how many times I go to Page Layout > Page Setup > Sheet > Comments > As displayed on sheet, they do not show up when trying to print.

It seems that I am not alone in this issue, as I've found a few threads on Microsoft support channels ([here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/comments-not-printing-or-exporting-in-excel-2019/096cdf79-71ee-40aa-bd5d-675a921d18ac) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-2016-for-mac-inserted-comments-are-not/d510da9f-037c-465b-a151-8ccee6540268), for example), but they mostly blame computer manufacturers and seem to deflect a lot.

Anyone have any idea how to get these comments to show up?

Comment: What year of Excel of Mac is it?

Comment: I'm using version 16.28, but have also downgraded to v15 and attempted the same thing with the same results.

Comment: See if you can find it in 'Page Setup' menu under the 'Sheet' tab. That is where it is kept. It should be there in all versions, Excel has a habit of making everything in Mac a little challenging to find but keeping everything there. It does often change the shortcuts but it is should be there.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two things that need to be set to print the comments.  One is Page Setup > Sheet > Comments (for each sheet in the Workbook).  The other is to set the Excel > Preferences > View > For Cells with Comments, Show > Comments and Indicators.